# Flutter: How to use responsive builder

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, responsive

**How to use this responsive package in my following code.**
**This is the link to the responsive package https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_builder**

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/background2.gif"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: it has got pretty neat documentation at pub

Comment: can you help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the SizeConfig class you're using is from this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a) and I personally haven't used that before. Nevertheless, using the responsive builder package is super simple.

First, replace your existing build method with something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenTypeLayout(
      mobile: mobileLayout(),
      tablet: tabletLayout(),
      desktop: desktopLayout(),
      watch: watchLayout(),
    );
}
```

When your FirstPage widget is built, the ScreenTypeLayout widget will automatically handle which "layout" widget should be returned based on the screen size. Inside each of the layout widgets, you can add another branch to the decision tree like this:

```
Widget mobileLayout(){
  // Return a widget function per orientation
  return OrientationLayoutBuilder(
    portrait: (context) => mobilePortrait(),
    landscape: (context) => mobileLandscape(),
  );
}
```

You can create each individual widget separately and then plug them into each layout how you see fit (ex. plugging them into Rows and Columns in the layout widgets).